# Prove that for all integers $x$ with final digit equal to $5$, $x$ is a multiple of $5$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

Is my proof for the statement in question correct?

Let $x \in\mathbb{Z} $ with $x=10r-5$ for some $r \in \mathbb {Z} $. Then for $n \in \mathbb {Z} $ we have $x=5 (2n-1)=5k $ where $k\in\mathbb {Z} $ is by definition odd. Thus, $x$ is divisible by $5$ and hence is a multiple of $5.$

Comment: Well, I think it is more natural to write $x=10m+5$, as in $575=10\times 57+5$, but otherwise it looks good.

Comment: How did you first establish that $\forall x \in \mathbb{Z}$ with find digit $5$, that number $x$ can be expressed in the form $x = 10r - 5$? .... I'm not disagreeing with you, I'm just curious as to how you established that first?

Comment: I just thought of a formula that would give me an integer with a final digit of 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Two nitpicks:

- In going from $x = 10r - 5$ to $x = 5(2n-1)$, there's no point in the change of variables, as $n=r$.
- No need for the stipulation $k$ is odd. It's nice that you notice that but it's not relevant to the proof.

Comment: Let $x \in\mathbb{Z} $ with $x=10r-5$ for some $r \in \mathbb {Z} $. Then $x=5 (2r-1)=5k $ for $k\in\mathbb {Z} $. Thus, $x$ is divisible by $5$ and hence is a multiple of $5.$

Comment: The proof looks much cleaner. I always feel the need to include every piece of information which is at times unecessary. Thanks for pointing this out for me. :)

Comment: Seems good! ^_^b And yeah, I understand that instinct, it's sooooo tempting. You learn to stop doing that with experience though.